# Greyscale darkening problem with Bitmap image in C#

Tags: c#, image, pointers, image-processing

I'm loading a 8bppIndexed greyscale image into memory and reading the pixel values.  The problem is that the values I am getting from the pixels do not seem to match the actual image, they are always darker.  My image is a simple grey gradient like this:

[image]

The bottom right pixel is returning 191 and the top left 0.  The top left is actually 64 and bottom right is 255.

Here is how I am loading my image:

```
Bitmap threshImg = new Bitmap(@"C:\grey.bmp");
```

Checking the PixelFormat confirms it is in Format8bppIndexed.  So I read the bottom right pixel and top left like so:

```
BitmapData data = threshImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
unsafe
{
    byte* pixel = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer();
    int topVal = (int)(byte)pixel[0];
    int bottomVal = (int)(byte)pixel[((threshImg.Height * threshImg.Width)) - 1];
}
threshImg.UnlockBits(data);
```

If I convert the image to 24bppRbg (and adjust the code accordingly) I see the correct colour values in the respective corners.

Anyone know why I'm getting darker values when using an 8bppIndexed image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the 8bpp indexed image isn't the color itself (or gray value) but the index. Try to look up the color value in the palette.

Comment: Took a look at the colour pallet, and the index matched the correct colour.  I just assumed the pallet would be an even distribution of greyscale covering 256 colours, but actually there was a range of 64 black colours from index 192 :-)

Answer (score 1):

With an indexed image there are only a certain number of colours (or in this case shades of grey) available - usually 256. It's probable that there aren't enough to get the full range of  shades in the original image.

As having the exact shades is important I'd shift to a 24bpp image.

Comment: The original image was saved in 8bpp format.  We are using greyscale video cameras set to 8bpp to keep within the bandwidth of a 1394a bus at high framerate, so the original image is guarenteed to be in this format.